# My Mac is not finding my files from my project

Tags: eclipse, macos

Ok so I have a Mac with eclipse and I done some stuff on my PC now I am transferring it to my Mac I got the .metadata to show but now it not reading it and finding my files so It just says the location the file is meant to be and then says does not exist when I try to open the project it says this ' 'Open Project' has encountered a problem. The project description file (.project) for 'Project3' is missing. This file contains important info about the project. The project will not function properly until this file is restored.' Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your projects should have a '.project' file (and possibly several other files starting with '.') in the project folder. On Macs (and Linux) these files are hidden and are not shown by Finder. So you need to be careful that they have been copied from your PC.

The command line tools you run in 'Terminal' on the Mac can show the '.' files with the correct options (`ls -a` for example).

Comment: Look I have the dot stuff but I never had a .project